# Which is better in umbraco elasticsearch or lucene

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, umbraco

I understand that generally speaking Elastic search is better to use in most cases but i would like to know specifically for Umbraco, whether it is as good to use or not? Or if lucene is better

Comment: Lucene is a search library, Elasticsearch is a search engine based on Lucene, Umbraco is a CMS. None of these are really directly comparable.

Comment: This question is unfortunately a bit too subjective for SO - there is no right answer and nothing which can be fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not use elastic search before, but I use Umbraco a lot and I use lucene, mainly via Examine which uses lucene.

Read about Examine here https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/searching/examine/

See an example of some advanced search I set up in Umbraco using Examine here
http://www.codeshare.co.uk/blog/how-to-search-by-document-type-and-property-in-umbraco/

Comment: New documentation for Umbraco Examine: https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/reference/searching/examine/